# ObjectId type in Java and MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

In java Spring and under MongoDB i declare a field `ObjectId` (`org.bson.types.ObjectId`) and find by id the associated object i get the field in this format :

```
"id": {
        "timestamp": 125945532265,
        "machineIdentifier": 1252265214,
        "processIdentifier": 127288,
        "counter": 936021898,
        "date": "2020-07-12T11:27:45.000+0000",
        "time": 1594553265000,
        "timeSecond": 1594553265
    }
```

which is different from Mongo's `"_id" : ObjectId("5f0af3b1e8556631f48ed602"),`

How to output the second format while getting objects ? which field definition in java is most suitable ??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [ObjectId#toHexString()](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#toHexString--) you'll get the value you expect. Both representations hold all the data in the id though.

Comment: To use it to return an objectId ? the whole json object ?

Comment: this is how the final returned id should look : `"_id": {
                "$oid": "5f031c5583b7c65e470b5106"
            }`